# Hidden things in CartoDB or MapBox

Tags: mapbox, cartodb

I am in a plan to use cartoDB or MapBox for one of my data visualization application. I would like to know whether is there any features restricted between shared codes and the own hosted solution? Is the shared codes missing any fancy stuffs?Is there any hidden things in their API's? What benefits one gets for the paid solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Those two companies have websites where they've posted detailed pricing plans and their benefits:

https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/

https://cartodb.com/pricing/